# Dynamic object in c# where the key has a $ sign

Tags: c#, dynamic

How to create a dynamic object of the below representation in c#. Guid is passed in as a parameter

```
{$addToSet : {childFolders: "Guid"}}
```

I tried this :

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.$addSet = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic; // This line gives me error on visual studio . Unexpected character '$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With [ExpandoObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).Add("$addSet", new ExpandoObject());

var addSet = ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando)["$addSet"] as dynamic;

addSet.childFolders = "Guid";
```

**With [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)**

```
dynamic obj = new JObject();
obj["$addSet"] = new JObject();
var addSet = obj["$addSet"];
addSet.childFolders = "Guid";
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `Dictionary<String, Object>` only instead and accessing the key through the indexer. ExpandoObject is something unnecessary.

Comment: @Transcendent my answer is based on keeping things `dynamic`.